# ExtJS store update to a MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, extjs, controller

When I call the `sync` method on a ExtJS `store` and there is one object to update, the proxy update method gets called with one object as parameter. 
If there are more objects to update, an array of objects is passed to the proxy update method.

The endpoint of my proxy is a MS MVC controller. I can't overload the requested method with a single object and a list of objects (not supported on a MVC controller due the model binding).

How can I make this work? (either update 1 object at a time from ExtJS, or use different requests for a single object or an array of objects)

ExtJS store:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.Configuration', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
requires: 'MyApp.model.Configuration',
model: 'MyApp.model.Configuration',
autoLoad: false,
isLoaded: false,
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    actionMethods: { create: 'POST', read: 'POST', update: 'POST', destroy: 'POST' },
    limitParam: undefined,
    pageParam: undefined,
    startParam: undefined,
    api: {
        read: 'MyAppData/ConfigurationRead',
        create: MyAppData/ConfigurationUpdate',
        update: MyAppData/ConfigurationUpdate',
        destroy: MyAppData/ConfigurationDelete'
    },
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'data',
        successProperty: 'success',
        messageProperty: 'message'
    }
},
```

MVC Controller, not working:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ConfigurationUpdate(List<Configuration> data)
    {
        // do something
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ConfigurationUpdate(Configuration data)
    {
        // do something
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the allowSingle config of the JSON writer? http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/source/Json3.html#Ext-data-writer-Json-cfg-allowSingle